# Let iPad only use one app and disable settings

Tags: ipad, security, settings

At the office where I work we are trying  to deploy iPads. We now have 16 iPads all around the company and we use Sophos Mobile Control to monitor and manage those iPads.

However, we found out this is not enough. Everytime I come across an iPad given to an employee, he changed things to the device or the software. Although we do have policies for that, the iPads are NOT covered by a BYOD-policy that would allow such things within the company.

After a lot of desperate tries to disable all sorts of things in the iPad (from trying to disable the Settings App to using a "sort-of" kiosk mode using one app) all solutions I came to didn't fit the whole need for clean devices.

When trying to disable settings, you just can't disable everything, and things like backgrounds etc. are still changeable by the employee. We don't want this since this iPad is kind of like a trademark for our company - we try to maintain a steady pace in developing and implementing new devices and ways to get the job done - and clients must in no way be confronted by the unprofessional backgrounds set on the iPads by those employees.

Whenever things are possible, people will try to (ab)use it. I want to have the control over what apps, settings and web pages can be viewed/used by the iPad users. Is there any way for us to change the way iPads secure themselves?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after the "apple enterprise configurator"

http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/enterprise/

I've not used it but it sounds like the (only) option.

http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/1.2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the guided access? I'm not that familiar with it, so it could be that this is just meant for temporary sessions. I understand the employees have longer access to the device?

[iOS: About Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Another option would be to lock the iPad into a single app. I wrote a blog post on this earlier. It worked for iOS 5, not sure about iOS 6. Though the enterprise configuratior might have options to enable this too:

[Kiosk mode for iOS](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/kiosk-mode-for-ios/)